# Using CheckSum with C++ for 13 Digit ISBN

Tags: c++, checksum, isbn

I am trying to calculate the final digit of a 13 digit ISBN using the first 12 digits using C++. I feel like my code should be correct but I have a feeling the formula I'm using may be wrong.

The formula is:

10 - (d0 + d1 * 3 + d2 + d3 * 3 + d4 + d5 * 3 + d6 + d7 * 3 + d8 + d9 * 3 + d10 + d11 * 3) % 10

Here's what I have:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int weightedSum = 0;
    int checksum = 0;
    int i;      //for loop decrement
    int mul = 3;
    const int LENGTH = 12;
    char ISBNinput[LENGTH];

    std::cout << "Enter first 12 digits of ISBN: ";   //ask user for input
    std::cin >> ISBNinput;       //stores input into ISBNinput
    std::cout << std::endl;

    for (i = 0;  i < strlen(ISBNinput);  i++) {

        weightedSum += (ISBNinput[i] % 12) * mul;

        if (mul == 3) {
            mul = 1;
        } else {
            mul = 3;
        }

    }//close for loop

    checksum = weightedSum % 10;        //calculates checksum from weightedSum

    std::cout << checksum << std::endl;       //prints checksum with new line for format

    return 0;
}
```

For example:

978007063546 should return 3

and

978032133487 should return 9

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Does your `int` type hold 12 digits? Either way you're always calculating on the same part of the input, since `ISBNinput % 12` never changes in the loop.

Comment: I think so. How would I know? (Sorry I'm a little new to C++)

Comment: Print the value for `std::numeric_limits<int>::max()`. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits

Comment: In order to access single decimal digits of a large number, you either need to use division and modulo, or you treat the number as a string. Keep in mind that `char` is also an integer type, but that `'9' != 9` though!

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I added the changes to the code above, but it still doesn't seem to want to calculate correctly. 
What else would I need to add?

(Thanks for your help btw)

Comment: That code doesn't even compile. Also, don't use `char` arrays, use `std::string`. Further, provide a single `main()` with twelve hardcoded digits, the output and the expected output, so that anyone can compile and run it.

Comment: Isn't the value of each number is character form? Doesn't he need to offset by `'0'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I go about this.

First, let's decide how we're going to test this.  I'll assume that we've written the function, and that it gives the correct output.  So I pick up a couple of books off my desk, and test that it works for them:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Book 1 - expect 3, got " << checksum("978032114653") << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Book 2 - expect 0, got " << checksum("978020163361") << std::endl;
}
```

Of course, when we try to compile that, we get an error.  So create the function, before `main()`:

```
char checksum(const char *s)
{
    return '1';
}
```

Now it compiles, but the result is always `1`, but now we can start to fill in the body.  Let's start with some smaller examples, that we can calculate by hand; add these at the beginning of `main()`:

```
    std::cout << "1 digit - expect 4, got " << checksum("6") << std::endl;
```

Now let's get this one working - this gives us conversion from character to digit and back, at least:

```
char checksum(const char *s)
{
    int digit = *s - '0';
    return '0' + 10 - digit;
}
```

Let's try 2 digits:

```
    std::cout << "1 digit - expect 6, got " << checksum("11") << std::endl;
```

And now our test fails again.  So add some more processing, to make this pass (and not break the single-digit test):

```
char checksum(const char *s)
{
    int sum = 0;
    int digit = *s - '0';
        sum += digit;
    ++s;
    if (*s) {
        digit = *s - '0';
        sum += 3 * digit;
    }
    return '0' + (10 - sum)%10;
}
```

We're probably ready to make this into a loop now.  Once that's passed, we no longer need the short tests, and I have:

```
#include <iostream>

char checksum(const char *s)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int mul = 1;  *s;  ++s) {
        int digit = *s - '0';
        sum += mul * digit;
        mul = 4 - mul;
    }
    return '0' + (1000 - sum)%10;
}

int test(const char *name, char expected, const char *input)
{
    char actual = checksum(input);
    if (actual == expected) {
        std::cout << "PASS: " << name << ": "
                  << input << " => " << actual
                  << std::endl;
        return 0;
    } else {
        std::cout << "FAIL: " << name << ": "
                  << input << " => " << actual
                  << " - expected " << expected
                  << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int failures = 0;
    failures += test("Book 1", '3', "978032114653");
    failures += test("Book 2", '0', "978020163361");
    return failures > 0;
}
```

I factored out the actual checking into a function here, so we can keep count of failures, and exit with the appropriate status, but everything else is as I described above.

You'll want to add a few more test cases - in particular, make sure the function correctly returns the extreme values `0` and `9` when it should.

Comment: BTW, the two books I picked up off the desk are recommended reading here - do look them up!

Answer (score 1):

There is one clear bug in your code: you are not allocating enough space in for `ISBNinput`.  You should make it one character longer:

```
const int LENGTH = 13;
```

The reason for this is that that character-array strings are terminated with an extra null character.  You might be lucky and the next byte in memory could sometimes happen to be a null byte, in which case the program would still work sometimes.

If you run the program with valgrind or a similar memory checker you are likely to see an error as the program access memory beyond what was allocated on the stack.

Also I think there is another bug.  I think that `mul` should be initialized to `1`.

By the way, this code is very fragile, depending on you entering no more than 12 characters, all of which are assumed to be digits.  It might be OK as a quick hack for a proof-of-concept, but should not be used in any real program.